# Flight with 9 holding patterns before landing on the wrong airport

Tags: airlines

[image: flight CZ3047]

Can someone explain why this happened? Quite odd why he cannot get landing clearance from atc. And is this common?

Comment: I would guess: holding due to weather (fog) for the maximum time possible and then diverting.

Comment: Can you specify the date and time (I don't see them in the screenshot) and flight number (it is there, but hard to read)?

Comment: Exact same thing as this which was closed. http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/23915/9-holding-patterns-before-landing-on-the-wrong-airport